# 2D animation into 3D animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, 3d

I'd like to turn this 2D animation of orbiting planets into a 3D animation, in order to visualize the trajectories in 3D, and if possible, add a trace to the trajectories:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 6.5)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10))
patch1 = plt.Circle((1, -1), 0.1, fc='b')
patch2 = plt.Circle((2, -2), 0.1, fc='r')
patch3 = plt.Circle((3, -3), 0.1, fc='r')

def init():
    patch1.center = (0, 0)
    patch2.center = (0, 0)
    patch3.center = (0, 0)
    ax.add_patch(patch1)
    ax.add_patch(patch2)
    ax.add_patch(patch3)
    return patch1, patch2, patch3,

def animate(i):
    x, y = patch1.center
    a, b = patch2.center
    u, v = patch3.center
    x = 0 + 3 * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    y = 0 + 3 * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    a = 0 + 1.5 * np.sin(np.radians(2*i))
    b = 0 + 1.5 * np.cos(np.radians(2*i))
    u = 0 + 5 * np.sin(np.radians(i/2))
    v = 0 + 5 * np.cos(np.radians(i/2))
    patch1.center = (x, y)
    patch2.center = (a, b)
    patch3.center = (u, v)
    return patch1, patch2, patch3,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                               init_func=init, 
                               frames=100000, 
                               interval=20,
                               blit=True)

plt.show()
```

I tried this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim3d(-10,10); 
ax.set_ylim3d(-10, 10);
ax.set_zlim3d(-10, 10);
```

plus adding a third coordinate to the rest of the code but nothing is displayed...

Answer (score 0):

The code [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html) shows a 3D-animation which you should be able to copy-paste and run directly.

You'll have to think a bit more about the plane of the orbit for each planet in 3D of course...